# Changing information shown in menu via javascript

Tags: javascript, hover, jquery-hover, megamenu

when my mega menu drops down, I have 4 tabs. currently the to view each of the tabs it is set to click,. I have tried to change this so hovering over the tabs changes the info shown in the menu.
The below code works perfectly when I enter it into www.bootply.com
However does not work on my site.

the tabs

```
<ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">   
    <li class="active change"><a href="#Featured" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Featured</a></li>
    <li class="change"><a href="#AtoC" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"># - C</a></li>
    <li class="change"><a href="#DtoL" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">D - L</a></li>
    <li class="change"><a href="#MtoP" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">M - P</a></li>
    <li class="change"><a href="#QtoZ" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Q - Z</a></li>
</ul>
```

should change with hover but I still require to click them.
I cannot figure out why the code works fine on bootply.com but not on my site

can anyone help? I am using wordpress CMS

PHP:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
    <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-megadropdown-tabs">
                <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            </button>
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="#"></a>
        </div>
        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="navbar-collapse style= collapse in" id="bs-megadropdown-tabs" style="padding-left: 0px;">
            <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                <li class="dropdown mega-dropdown">
                    <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown"> <i class="fa fa-space-shuttle"></i> CATEGORIES <span class="caret"></span></a>              
                    <div id="filters" class="dropdown-menu mega-dropdown-menu">
                        <div class="container-fluid2">
                            <!-- Tab panes -->
                            <div class="tab-content">
                                <div class="tab-pane active" id="Featured">
                                    <ul class="nav-list list-inline">
                                        <li><a data-filter=".89" href="#"><img src="#"><span>ABC</span></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="AtoC">
                                    <ul class="nav-list list-inline">                                
                                        <li><a data-filter=".38" href="#"><span>DEF</span></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="DtoL">
                                    <ul class="nav-list list-inline">
                                        <li><a href="#"><span>HIL</span></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="MtoP">
                                    <ul class="nav-list list-inline">
                                        <li><a href="#"><span>KLM</span></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                                <div class="tab-pane" id="QtoZ">
                                    <ul class="nav-list list-inline">
                                        <li><a href="#"><span>NOP</span></a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        <!-- Nav tabs -->
                        <ul class="nav nav-tabs" role="tablist">   
                            <li class="active change"><a href="#Featured" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Featured</a></li>
                            <li class="change"><a href="#AtoC" role="tab" data-toggle="tab"># - C</a></li>
                            <li class="change"><a href="#DtoL" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">D - L</a></li>
                            <li class="change"><a href="#MtoP" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">M - P</a></li>
                            <li class="change"><a href="#QtoZ" role="tab" data-toggle="tab">Q - Z</a></li>
                        </ul>                    
                    </div>              
                </li>
            </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
    </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
</nav>
```

CSS:

```
.navbar-brand { 
    width: 70px;
    height: 50px;
    background: url('http://www.sneaker-
mission.com/uploads/3/1/2/7/31279819/5617441.png') no-repeat center center;
    background-size: 50px;  
  }
  .col-md-4{
      width:15%;
  }
  .nav-tabs {
    display: inline-block;
    border-bottom: none;
    padding-top: 0.5vw;
    font-weight: bold;
    border-top: 2px solid #d52027;
  }
  .nav-tabs > li > a, 
  .nav-tabs > li > a:hover, 
  .nav-tabs > li > a:focus, 
  .nav-tabs > li.active > a, 
  .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover,
  .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
    border: none;
    border-radius: 0;
  }
  .nav-tabs > li > a{
      color:#d52027
  }
  .nav-list { border-bottom: px solid #eee; }
  .nav-list > li { 
    padding: 20px 15px 15px;

  }
  .nav-list > li:last-child { border-right: 0px solid #eee; }
  .nav-list > li > a:hover { text-decoration: none; }
  .nav-list > li > a > span {
    display: block;
    font-weight: bold;
    text-transform: uppercase;
  }

  .mega-dropdown { position: static !important; }
  .mega-dropdown-menu {
    padding: 20px 15px 15px;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
  }
  #login-dp{
      min-width: 250px;
      padding: 14px 14px 0;
      overflow:hidden;
      background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.8);
  }
  #login-dp .help-block{
      font-size:12px    
  }
  #login-dp .bottom{
      background-color:rgba(255,255,255,.8);
      border-top:1px solid #ddd;
      clear:both;
      padding:14px;
  }
  #login-dp .social-buttons{
      margin:12px 0    
  }
  #login-dp .social-buttons a{
      width: 49%;
  }
  #login-dp .form-group {
      margin-bottom: 10px;
  }
  .btn-fb{
      color: #fff;
      background-color:#3b5998;
  }
  .btn-fb:hover{
      color: #fff;
      background-color:#496ebc 
  }
  .btn-tw{
      color: #fff;
      background-color:#55acee;
  }
  .btn-tw:hover{
      color: #fff;
      background-color:#59b5fa;
  }
   .row>ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    list-style-position:none;
    list-style-image:none;
  }
  .row1>ul {
    list-style-type:none;
    list-style-position:none;
    list-style-image:none;
  }

  @media(max-width:768px){
      #login-dp{
          background-color: inherit;
          color: #fff;
      }
      #login-dp .bottom{
          background-color: inherit;
          border-top:0 none;
      }
  }
  .navbar-login
  {
      width: 305px;
      padding: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 0px;
  }

  .navbar-login-session
  {
      padding: 10px;
      padding-bottom: 0px;
      padding-top: 0px;
  }

  .icon-size
  {
      font-size: 87px;
  }
  .navbar-brand {
      width: 70px;
      height: 50px;
      background: url('http://www.sneaker-
mission.com/uploads/3/1/2/7/31279819/5617441.png') no-repeat center center;
      background-size: 50px;
      padding-top: 7px;
  }
  .navbar-nav {
      padding-left: 15px;
  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-collapse, .navbar-default .navbar-form {
      border-color: #00486c;
  }
  .container-fluid {
      padding-right: 15px;
      padding-left: 15px;
      margin-right: auto;
      margin-left: auto;
      background-color: rgb(51,79,111);
      position: relative;
      right: 0.5vw;
      width: 100vw;

  }
 .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:hover, .navbar-default .navbar-nav>.active>a:focus {
      color: white;
      background-color: #428bca;

  }
  .navbar-default .navbar-nav>li>a {
      color: white;
  }
  .dropdown-menu {
      position: absolute;
      top: 100%;
      left: 0px;
      z-index: 1000;
      display: none;
      float: left;
      min-width: 160px;
      padding: 5px 0px;
      margin: 2px 0px 0px;
      font-size: 14px;
      list-style: none;
      background-color: white;
      -webkit-background-clip: padding-box;
      background-clip: padding-box;
      border: 1px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14902);
      border-image-source: initial;
      border-image-slice: initial;
      border-image-width: initial;
      border-image-outset: initial;
      border-image-repeat: initial;
      border-radius: 4px;
      box-shadow: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.172549) 0px 6px 12px;
      left:15vw;
      width:70vw;
  }
  .nav-list > li {
      padding: 20px 15px 15px;
      border-left:0px;
  }
  .nav-list {
      border-bottom: 0px;
  }
  .nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
      color: white;
      cursor: default;
      background-color: #428bca;
  }
  .nav-tabs > li.active > a, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:hover, .nav-tabs > li.active > a:focus {
      color: black;
      cursor: default;
      background-color: rgb(255, 255, 255);
      border: solid black 1px;
  }
  body
  {
      padding-top: 20px;
  }
```

Javascript

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$(".dropdown").hover(            
    function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).slideDown("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass('open');        
    },
    function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).slideUp("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass('open');       
    }
);
});
$('.change>a').hover(function() { 
    $(this)[0].click();
}, 
    function() {
    /* code for mouseout */
    });
```

Comment: Are all the libraries that you're using in the bootply page being added from your assets for the site? Do you get any errors in your console? Are you using the same browser ?

Answer (score 0):

For wordpress the jQuery `$` alias does not work by default. Use `jQuery` instead. Or pass `$` in via `.ready` like this:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($){
  // can use $ here
});
```

Also put your `.hover` code inside `.ready`.

NOTE: seeing wordpress and $ ... I did not check your code..

Comment: Thank you for your reply... Can I check my understanding on this though... My confusion is that, in my script, there are 2 javascrip functions, one to initiate dropdown from the main nav bar

    $(document).ready(function(){
    $(".dropdown").hover(            
    function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).slideDown("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass('open');        
    },
    function() {
        $('.dropdown-menu', this).stop( true, true ).slideUp("fast");
        $(this).toggleClass('open');       
    }
    );
    });

Comment: this one contains the     $ alias but works fine... is it the     .ready(function() part which needs included?

Comment: If you talk about 2 function inside `.hover`: first one is for `mouseenter` event, the second one is for `mouseleave`. Re the `$` working well: are you sure? Re the `.ready`: it's adviced to put immediately executed jQuery code inside it. Read http://api.jquery.com/ready/

Comment: If your site is online, can you give us a link?

Comment: Hi thanks again for your reply. I am a complete newbie to Javascript as have always tried this sort of thing using CSS but CSS is not powerful enough to do what I need. my site is online but this menu is still being tested via localhost and has not been uploaded as yet until it is working properly

Comment: I hope my reply didnt come across as cheeky :-( just keen to try and understand a bit better.  the dropdown works so I am assuming this is due to the first javascript command and has worked with the $ alias which is why i am puzzled why the second wont work with it, and even more puzzled now how the first manages to work lol

Comment: would the fact that I reference src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js" on my site make a difference and maybe explain why the top script works?

Comment: Don't worry about being cheeky. Including jquery can cause trouble, as wp already enqueues it by default (though themes or plugins can dequeue it). So, remove that jquery then check your console for errors. Also see zfrisch comment above.

Comment: btw, with "the second" function you meant the `$('.change>a')` code? Place it inside the `jQuery().ready(){ ... }` to be sure it gets executed properly.

Comment: I have tried a few variations... jQuery().ready(){$('.change>a')...}... also... jQuery(document).ready(function($){$('.change>a')... and the same 2 again replacing jQuery with $ and none seem to work. infact they actually seem to stop the dropdown script above it from working.

Comment: I also tried using https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js as currently using https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js but that had no effect other than causing the dropdown menu to act erratic. I genuinley do not know what to do

Comment: Thank you for all yer help @yezzz. I have figured it out... i had jQuery('.change>a')... i simply changed '' to "" ... ("change>a") and now it works fine :-)... thanks again

Comment: You're welcome. So you're saying double quotes solved it? And $ was working? Maybe due to another library (bootstrap??)... anyway normally it should work with single quotes, see this example: https://jsfiddle.net/uswtggwg/

Comment: yip double quotes Was the answer lol. You've been great.  Thanks a lot :-)